# MVC model property passed as null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model, editorfor, strongly-typed-view, editortemplates

I have a strongly typed views where I pass editors for several properties eg.

```
public class BookingModel
{
    public FirstPropertyModel FirstProperty { get; set; }
    public SecondPropertyModel SecondProperty { get; set; }
    public ThirdPropertyModel ThirdProperty { get; set; }
}

@model MyWebsite.Models.BookingModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("Order", "Booking", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "order_summary" }))
{
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstProperty, "_FirstProperty")
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SecondProperty, "_SecondProperty")
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ThirdProperty, "_ThirdProperty")
    <input type="submit" id="btnOrder" value="Order" />
}
```

All properties objects are passed to the action nicely but one property (First) which comes as null.

They all are within EditorTemplates and their views are also strongly types - use their own models.

ANy idea why is this happening?

Comment: How are the templates `_FirstProperty` etc. defined?

Comment: I had a problem with some model properties displaying on the property view, so after fixing the property null issue has been fixed. Thank you for replies

Comment: If possible, please add your own answer describing the fix (and then accept it). This allows future developers who come to this question to know the solution and, if applicable, make use of it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try initializing/instantiating the BookingModel properties in the constructor to see if that helps

```
public class BookingModel
{
    public BookingModel()
    {
        FirstProperty = new FirstPropertyModel();
        SecondProperty = new SecondPropertyModel();
        ThirdProperty = new ThirdPropertyModel();
    }
    public FirstPropertyModel FirstProperty { get; set; }
    public SecondPropertyModel SecondProperty { get; set; }
    public ThirdPropertyModel ThirdProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with some model properties displaying on the property view, so after fixing the property null issue has been fixed. Thank you for replies